How to validate that a deployment is done successful form a Kubernetes@1 from an azure pipeline?
I have an azure pipeline that deploys a image to a kubernetes cluster using a Kubernetes@1 task:
- task: Kubernetes@1
inputs:
  connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
  kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ...
  namespace: mynamespace
  command: apply
  arguments: -k kubernetes/
  secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
  containerRegistryType: 'Container Registry'
  dockerRegistryEndpoint: myendpoint...

It all works and deploys successfully.
But how can I verify that the deploy was successful? Ideally I would like the deployment to wait until everything was deployed successful.
There is another post that has something similar and suggest to use a kubectl wait commando.
I think I could do something like this to check the pods:
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod --all --namespace=bad --timeout=10s

Again not sure if the pods is the best thing to check. I also cannot check with the pod name as the name will be different each time.
And I have no idea how to hook it up to my pipeline. I tried adding a script task below my Kubernetes@1 task but that has no context of my kubernetes cluster and tries to connect to localhost:8080
  - task: Kubernetes@1
           ....
  - script: |
      kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod --all --namespace=bad --timeout=10s
    displayName: Execute kubectl
    env:
      KUBECONFIG: $(KUBECONFIG)

How do I add this to my azure pipeline or is there a better way to go about it?


But how can I verify that the deploy was successful? Ideally I would like the deployment to wait until everything was deployed successful.

The task Kubernetes@1 will return status of the deployment by default, if the task succeeds, which means the deployment is successful.
In addition, the task has output variable which stores the output of the kubectl command. You can echo "$(taskname.KubectlOutput)" to check the details(sample here).
If you would like to use kubectl wait --for=condition=ready... to check the pod status, you can add one more Kubernetes@1 task.
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'kubectl task'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: AKSConn2
    command: wait
    arguments: '--for=condition=ready pod --all --namespace=default --timeout=60s'

